# loading xml asynchronously in testcomplete using jscript

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

I am trying to load xml file asynchronously but when i call 
LoadXML(docname) in TestConfiguration() and print the return value ,
it does not print anything.

```
function TestConfiguration()
{
    var strFilePath = "..\\CommonFiles\\TestConfig.xml";
    var retVal = LoadXML(strFilePath);
    Log.Message(retVal);
}
function LoadXML(docname)
    {
    try {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    }
    catch(e) {
        Log.Message(e.message);
    }
    try {
        xmlDoc.async=true;
        xmlDoc.load(docname);
        return(xmlDoc);
    }
    catch(e) {
    Log.Message(e.message);
    }
    return(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put the XML Doc object to the Log.Message method. This is an object and cannot be printed. You need to print this object's XML property instead:

```
function TestConfiguration()
{
    var strFilePath = "..\\CommonFiles\\TestConfig.xml";
    var retVal = LoadXML(strFilePath);
    Log.Message(retVal.xml);
}
```

Comment: How do i return success or failure after reading the xml nodes and its attributes to the caller. Any function which could help to do it ?

Comment: To understand whether an operation is successful, you can check its result for null - (retVal.selectSingleNode("kkk") == null). BTT, I would appreciate it if you marked my answer as accepted.